# Axis2 cookie clean up

Tags: cookies, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 1.3 for my API client & server.
We have multiple instance at production and we are load balance using L4 switch (Netscalar). To hit same instance for consequence call, L4 switch use stick cookie.

It is good for service , but I need to hit other instance in some case.
For web application, we could do it by deleting cache from browser.
But, I don't know whether cookie is kept for axis2.

Could you let me know whether cookie is kept for axis2 ( or Java ) and how I could delete it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Axis2 may use cookies. You can get HTTP headers using

```
MessageContext context = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);
Object prop = context.getProperty("Set-Cookie");
```

And you can set headers using following code.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Header header = new Header();  
header.setName("Cookie");  
header.setValue("my cookie");      
list.add(header);  

options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, list);  
client.setOptions(options);
```